# Android Share intent, remain in the same Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, share

I want to implement a share functionality

```
        Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("text/plain");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Awesome Keyboard");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.codeofaninja.com");
        mShare = true;
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share with"));
```

and everything  it's OK. But the problem that I'm dealing with is that once I clicked share button my Activity goes through `onPause()`, `onStop()`, `onDestroy()` and of course sends the user to MainActivity.

What  can I do to stop preventing the app going to  MainActivity?

I've tried to override `finish()` method and set `moveTaskToBack(true);` but it shout downs the app.

Comment: "and of course sends the user to MainActivity" -- what do you mean by "sends the user to MainActivity"? Your code will launch some `ACTION_SEND` implementation's activity, unless the user backs out of the chooser.

Comment: From which activity you are calling this activty?Do you want to stay in the same activity?

Comment: Yes @AbhijitChakra, I want to stay in the  same activity. MyActivity extends  BaseActivity(if this helps you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem. In my particulare case. The intent to go fom MainActivity to The SecondActivity ( from which the share intent was implemented), it had this flag 'intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);' , which was the trouble that my SecondActivty was destroyed

Answer (score 1):

To avoid calling on destroy you can call this below code snippets.

Try using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` when starting child activity, like:

Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id,
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP));

Comment: what do you mean by child activity?

Comment: when u call startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share with")); this activity is a child activty.

Comment: I don't know where to write it.

Comment: `Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("text/plain");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Awesome Keyboard");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.codeofaninja.com");
            share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share with"));`

Comment: looks like perfect

Comment: I have multiple devices. On Android 4.0.4 I don't have this problem. But on devices with OS 5.0.1 and 6.0 I have this problem

Comment: I've solved my problem. In my particulare case. The intent to go fom MainActivity to The SecondActivity ( from which the share  intent was implemented), it had this flag 'intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);' , which was the trouble that my SecondActivty was destroyed